# Maven verify плагин

Tags: maven, java

Добрый день!
Нигде, почему-то нет информации, что делает этот плагин.
Единственное, что по нему можно найти, эта фраза :

> verify - run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria

Она , наверное, слишком очевидна ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Описанный вами `verify` - это не плагин, а фаза жизненного цикла maven-а. Поэтому описание такое краткое. Сама по себе фаза ничего не делает. Но на нее могут назначаться плагины, попадающие под это описание: "выполнение любых проверок для верификации пакета на валидность и соответствие критериям качества".

Самый простой пример: цель `check` плагина `findbugs` по-умолчанию исполняется в этой фазе (разумеется, когда плагин подключен). Плагин выполняет статический анализ качества кода,  для него в этой фазе самое место.

---

**UPD0.** За каждой фазой стоит 0..* плагинов (точнее, их целей - *goals*). Плагины, которые назначены по-умолчанию на самом деле описаны в т.н. *Super POM* - модели, которую неявно наследуют все ваши pom-файлы.

Чтобы наверняка знать, какие плагины стоят за каждой фазой, вы можете выполнить команду:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Maven поднапряжется и выдаст вам сводный pom (*effective pom*), содержащий унаследованные опции из всех родительских моделей.

Для моей версии maven-а (3.3.1), например, справедливы следующие умолчания:

1. **clean**: `maven-clean-plugin:clean`
2. **process-resources**: `maven-resources-plugin:resources`
3. **compile**: `maven-compiler-plugin:compile`
4. **process-test-resources**: `maven-resources-plugin:testResources`
5. **test-compile**: `maven-compiler-plugin:testCompile`
6. **test**: `maven-surefire-plugin:test`
7. **package**: `maven-jar-plugin:jar`
8. **install**: `maven-install-plugin:install`
9. **deploy**: `maven-deploy-plugin:deploy`
10. **site**: `maven-site-plugin:site`
11. **site-deploy**: `maven-site-plugin:deploy`

Как видите для многих фаз (всего их около 30) никакие плагины не назначены. Про назначения по-умолчанию для разных типов maven-проектов можно прочитать в [документации](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings).

Comment: зы. maven достаточно сложная штука, чтобы разбираться в нем методом тыка. Рекомендую [какое-нибудь чтиво](https://maven.apache.org/articles.html). *Better Builds with Maven* свободно распространялся, например.

Comment: *Описанный вами verify - это не плагин* .Мне казалось, что за каждой фазой стоит плагин, который выполняется по-умолчанию. Спасибо за ссылку

Comment: @voipp, смотрите обновление ответа.